# Can you access Questions attached to Event via Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook Event and have a Question / Poll on the Event Wall. I can't seem to find a way via the Graph API to access the Question as it relates to the Event.

If I access "my" questions (via. https://graph.facebook.com/me/questions) I can see the Question but there is no field that shows which Event it relates to. Accessing the Event /feed only shows wall posts that my access token has access to, but not the Question.

Basically is there any way with the Graph API to get Questions for an Event - whether via the User that posted the Question or via the Event?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are getting a Poll\Question on to an Event Wall but if it is there you should be able to retrieve it from /{event_id}/feed.  Questions in a feed are identified with a type of "question" and the creator of the question is identified in the from->id value.

Comment: For my testing I was just adding the Question via the Facebook website - ie. go to the Event page, click on "Ask Question" and fill it in.  I can't see it in {event}/feed though (however I can see a normal post I added.  Note that Facebook documentation only mentions being able to access links, posts and status messages through /feed, so maybe it's just unsupported to access Questions this way through the API.

Comment: I see - I was looking at Events created by a page and the Ask A Question option was not available - but the /feed is.  Surprisingly (or not for FB) an event created by a user has the Ask A Question option but /feed always returns nothing but and empty data node.